# Readers–writer lock Multithreading Scenario?

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization

I have read a few links about Readers–writer lock. I had few doubts.

1. In case the system has to be designed for Multiple reads and single write ,and write should have priority.
2. In case the system has to be designed for multiple reads and multiple write

So should we be implementing a semaphore for multiple read and a mutex for multiple write? or when do i use a critical section?
Also,Does it depend on the operating system? (does it differ in case of Unix and Windows)?

Comment: There are a lot of different names for different synchronisation primitives which are either equivalent or very similar. In C++, the standard way to perform synchronisation is with the mutex and lock objects in the standard library (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread)). The basic ideas in all multi-threaded code are to avoid race-conditions and to avoid lock contention.

Comment: Do you know any real use of multiple writers scenario?

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out what you're asking here...

Comment: Many OS's now have native SWMR (Single Writer Multi Reader) lock implementations. Even Windows finally got one with the Vista/S2K8 kernels. Pthreads has one, Boost has one, so pick one and go with it. no reason to reinvent it (but always interesting to learn how).